# {w is in {a,b}*|w contains b only in some odds position}

Tags: regex, regular-language, dfa, pumping-lemma

I need the DFA and the regular expression for this language.
[image: My dfa]

I think the DFA is this but the Regular expression I get is this ((aUb)a)* and I think it's not correct.

Comment: It should be `((a|b)a)*a?`

Comment: Thank you but I think it's Not, because your regex is not going to accept b, using the DFA to regex conversion now and I think I got it: ((aa|ba)*a)|((aa|ba)*b)|(aa|ba)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DFA to regex conversion now and I think I got it:

> ((aa|ba)*a)|((aa|ba)*b)|(aa|ba)*

Simplified as @Bergi said:

> (aa|ba)*|(a|b|ε)

Comment: I'd simplify to `(aa|ba)*(a|b|)`

Comment: Sure why not @Bergi